# How to change url with .htaccess's RewriteEngine?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

I need a regular expression to change url like 'domainame.com/foldername/index.php?id=123' to 'domainame.com/foldername/123'. But if there is something else instead of 'id' like 'domainame.com/foldername/index.php?someid=321', than it would change the same way, to 'domainame.com/foldername/321'.

Comment: It's not clear for me, do you want to rewrite both `id=123` and `someid=123` to `foldername/321` or just `id=123` or all query strings?

Comment: `domainname.com/foldername/` you want to match always after it or it can  be of different format ?

Comment: Examples: `site.com/folder1/index.php?thisid=1` = `site.com/folder1/1`; `site.com/folder1/index.php?thisid=2` = `site.com/folder1/2`; `site.com/folder1/index.php?thatid=3` = `site.com/folder1/3`; `site.com/folder2/index.php?moreid=4` = `site.com/folder2/4`.